# Переполнение целого при выделении памяти для массива объектов

Tags: c++, исключения, выделение-памяти

В языке **C** обычно выделение памяти осуществляется при помощи функции `malloc()` и подобных ей, поэтому проверки целочисленного переполнения и успешности выделения памяти нужно делать явно:

```
const size_t arr_size = count * sizeof(double);
// Контроль переполнения arr_size до или после операции умножения.
// ...
double *new_arr = malloc(arr_size);
// Контроль успешности выделения памяти.
// ...
memcpy(new_arr, some_arr, arr_size);
```

Подскажите, нужно ли в следующем коде **C++** обеспечивать проверку целочисленного переполнения при умножении?

```
unique_ptr<double[]> new_arr{ new double[count] };
memcpy(new_arr.get(), some_arr.get(), sizeof(double) * count );
```

Я полагаю, что `sizeof(double) * count` не нуждается в проверке, потому что если переполнение при этой операции и произойдет, то оно случится в операторе `new`, который сгенерирует соответствующее исключение `std::bad_array_new_length`.

Это так?

Comment: Нет никаких причин считать, что будет исключение. Проверка нужна.

Comment: @ixSci, разве это не случится? : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/bad_array_new_length

Comment: Максим, какая из описанный по ссылке ситуаций подходит к Вашему случаю, по Вашему мнению?

Comment: Возможно вторая, но я не уверен, потому что не понимаю, что именно проверяет **new**, просто тот факт, что **count*sizeof(type)** больше максимально допустимого размера, или все же проводится проверка целочисленного переполнения...

Comment: Хорошо, пусть будет вторая. Мы знаем «implementation-defined maximum value»?

Comment: Нет, не знаем. Но если **new** и в самом деле не проверяет возможное переполнение при умножении **sizeof(type)*count**, то это выглядит весьма странно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На первый взгляд защищаться от переполнения во внутренних вычислениях `new[]` не нужно - это обязанность самого `new[]`. Как вы сами правильно заметили, превышение максимально допустимого размера массива приводит к выбросу исключения. (В популярных реализациях это превышение наступит раньше, чем будет переполнен диапазон `size_t`, так как максимальный размер объекта обычно ограничен *половиной* этого диапазона). К слову, аналогичные обязанности возложены и на функцию `calloc` в стандартной библиотеке С - она обязана самостоятельно следить за отсутствием переполнения при вычислении полного размера блока.

Тема арифметического переполнения в `new[]` поднималась в [DR#256](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#256), в котором, с одной стороны, проверку сочли тривиальной, но с другой стороны решили, что требовать ее обязательного выполнения было бы избыточным из-за накладных расходов. Реализациям предлагалось опционально предоставлять возможность такой проверки с выбрасыванием `std::bad_alloc`.

Затем эта тем была еще раз рассмотрена в [DR#624](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#624) и [DR#805](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#805), где вроде бы утверждается, что накладные расходы в этом случае настолько ничтожны, что проверку стоило бы сделать постоянной. Также решено, что выбрасывание `std::bad_alloc` - не самая лучшая идея. Исключение поменяли сначала на `std::length_error`. Затем `std::length_error` тоже сочли плохим выбором, и поменяли исключение на "что-то унаследованное от `std::bad_alloc`", что и привело к нынешнему `std::bad_array_new_length`.

Однако из последних ссылок не ясно, что все таки решили сделать с требованием необходимости проверки переполнения. С одной стороны, я не вижу там жесткого требования такой проверки. С другой стороны, я не вижу, как реализация может удовлетворить внешней спецификации `new[]` без выполнения такой проверки. Скорее всего, замысел резолюции DR#256 заключался в том, чтобы сказать, что формально такая проверка нужна, но на практике необходимость в ней настолько ничтожна, что реализовывать ее не обязательно.

Так что в вашем примере кода формально действительно не нужно делать никаких дополнительных проверок. Если `new[]` завершился успешно, значит арифметического переполнения заведомо не произошло.

Comment: Больше спасибо за столь доходчивый ответ)

Comment: А что по этой ситуации говорится в Стандарте? Я искал, но то ли смотрел не те черновики, то ли просто не нашел... Мне удалось узнать лишь то, что **new** начал бросать исключение **bad_array_new_length** начиная с **C++11**.

Comment: @Максим, а в стандарте в этом вопросе полный бардак (что, кстати, для С++ не редкость). В описании `new` пишется "_throws std::bad_alloc or another exception derived from std::bad_alloc_", но в описании `bad_alloc` никаких производных классов нет. Все разъясняется если посмотреть описание `bad_array_new_length`, там видна иерархия. То есть к `bad_alloc` приделали новое производное исключение `bad_array_new_length`, но исправить описание `bad_alloc` забыли.

Comment: Не очень понял последнее предложение *"Если new[] завершился успешно, значит арифметического переполнения заведомо не произошло."* Ведь операнд `new[]` вычисляется до вызова `new[]` и при беззнаковом "переполнении" значение просто пойдёт на новый круг. В частности, получится небольшое число, которое вполне удачно обработается `new[]`.

Comment: @alexolut, имеется в виду «внутреннее переполнение». Т.е. `new` «снаружи» выделяет объектами, а внутри него память выделяется байтами, количество объектов может помещаться в беззнаковый тип, а количество байт, при этом — нет.

Answer (score 0):

Выделение в проверке не нуждается (будет выброшено bad_alloc если что), а вот с memset у вас есть проблемка. Напишите лучше вот так:

```
  unique_ptr<double[]> arr = make_unique<double[]>(size);
  memset(arr.get(), 0, sizeof(double) * size);
```

О переполнении заботиться не нужно, потому что вы просто столько памяти не выделите. Не забывайте, что в 64-битовой программе size_t будет тоже 64-битовым.

Дополнение: Visual C++ при попытке зарезервировать блок размера `sizeof(double) * ULLONG_MAX` выбрасывает исключение bad_array_new_length. Но поскольку в стандарте говорится только о bad_alloc, то если вам нужна абсолютная уверенность для любого компилятора - делайте проверку.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84484/discussion-on-answer-by-freim-------).

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю зачем вам это нужно, но переполнение будет возникать, если вы будете пытаться выделить больше, чем numeric_limits::max() / sizeof(double) памяти, а это больше
2097151 терабайт (!!)

```
if (count > std::numeric_limits<std::size_t>::max() / sizeof(double)) throw;
```

Answer (score 0):

Смотрите, возьмём Ваш код:

```
unique_ptr<double[]> new_arr{ new double[count] };
memcpy(new_arr.get(), some_arr.get(), sizeof(double) * count );
```

Что здесь может произойти? Варианта 2, память будет либо выделена, либо выделена не будет. В первом случае происходит успешное выделение и переход на вторую строчку; во втором случае происходит исключение и переход на вторую строчку не происходит. Второй случай нам не интересен.

Первый случай можно разложить ещё на 2:

1. `sizeof(double) * count > std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max()`
2. `sizeof(double) * count <= std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max()`

Результатом первой операции будет `sizeof(double) * count - std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max()`. Оба варианта спокойно могут быть выделены, просто, возможно, мы не хотим получения первого. Какой бы из этих вариантов не получился, мы получим в `memcpy` ровно то, что и просим. Т.е. вот такое для первого варианта (псевдокод):

```
memcpy(new_arr.get(), some_arr.get(), sizeof(double) * count - std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max());
```

Или для второго:

```
memcpy(new_arr.get(), some_arr.get(), sizeof(double) * count);
```

Оба этих варианта корректны с точки зрения того, что они не делают ничего такого, чего от них не просят. Поэтому, с этой точки зрения, никакая проверка не нужна. Потому что она не имеет никакого смысла. Проверку на переполнение имеет смысла выносить до выделения памяти, т.к. после этого она просто бесполезна.

В общем же случае, полагаться на то, что будет `std::bad_alloc` не стоит, т.к. нет никаких причин его ожидать без знания особенностей платформы.

Comment: Так сам **new** не проверяет переполнение при умножении?

Comment: @Максим, стандарт такого не требует, но может быть проверка на максимально допустимое значение. Это зависит от реализации.

Comment: @Максим, сделал простой эксперимент: `auto ptr = new double[std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max()];`, студия вызывает `malloc`, получает там `0` и бросает исключение. Никаких предварительных проверок там нет.

Comment: @Максим, хотя MSVC не допускает ситуации 2.1 из моего ответа, т.е. если результирующий размер больше, чем `std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max()`, тогда используется `std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max()`, что, в целом, можно принять как предварительную проверку.

Comment: Чтобы случай #1 произошёл нужно слева иметь тип с рангом `> size_t`. Или Вы о математическом неравенстве без языковых ограничений?

Comment: @alexolut, без языковых ограничений, исключительно математика.